# smalldatetime conversion

Tags: sql-server, ruby

how do I convert a Time object in Ruby to a string that can be converted to a Sqlserver's `smalldatetime` field without losing information about TZ and DST (if possible)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Smalldatetime has by definition no information about TZ and DST.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182418.aspx

Comment: Ok, but I guess I could add/subtract hours according to TZ and DST. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Simone - If you need to store the TZ and DST information why are you using a `smalldatetime`? Keep it simple and use `datetime` or `datetime2`

Comment: @Tony ok, so I guess the right solution is to check with the DBA to change the field's type.

Comment: @Simone - Yes, I'd see if you can get the data type changed. Although the data will take up more space (if saving space was the reason `smalldatetime` was chosen) you'll lose that advantage by having to storing the TZ and DST info as well. Also, with `smalldatetime` the time portion is only accurate to one minute; is that suitable for your use?

Comment: @Tony yes, the reason is space (that table has millions of records) and yes, a minute is accurate enough